# UIActivityViewController & UIDocumentInteractionController not showing options

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am new to UIActivityViewController and perhaps I am missing a basic understanding. What I am trying to do is attached a csv, xml and vcard file to activity controller and show dropbox, google drive etc options. I have downloaded and installed dropbox, google drive etc apps on my iPhone.

Now when I launch UIActivityViewController all I see are default message and email app in my acitivity controller. How can I have other apps show up on their too? Do I need to install each and every apps individual SDKs and somehow incorporate them in my app?

This is what I wold like to see

[image]

but this is what I see instead.

[image]

Here's the code that I have tried so far

```
-(IBAction) dropBoxAction
{

    paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask ,YES);
    NSString* documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    //CSV
    NSMutableString *fileNameStr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"test_CSV_Backup.csv"];
    NSString* csvDataFileStr = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameStr];
    NSData *csvData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:csvDataFileStr];

    //EXCEL
    NSMutableString *fileNameStr2 = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"test_EXCEL_Backup.xml"];
    NSString* excelDataFileStr = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameStr2];
    NSData *excelData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:excelDataFileStr];

    //VCARD
    NSMutableString *fileNameStr3 = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"test_VCARD_Backup.vcf"];
    NSString* vcardDataFileStr = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameStr3];
    NSData *vcardData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:vcardDataFileStr];


    //adding them all together
    NSMutableArray *sharingItems = [NSMutableArray new];
    [sharingItems addObject:csvData];
    [sharingItems addObject:excelData];
    [sharingItems addObject:vcardData];

    UIActivity *activity = [[UIActivity alloc] init];
    NSArray *applicationActivities = @[activity];

    UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharingItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];
    [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @rmaddy said, you should use `UIDocumentInteractionController` to replace `UIActivityViewController`, just like this:

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *dc = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileNameStr]];
[dc presentOptionsMenuFromRect:self.view.bounds inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I was stuck that is exactly the missing code I needed. You answer is marked.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone interested in future, here's the code all in one place. Do rate it up if this helps.

In your *.h file add this

```
@interface v1BackupComplete : UIViewController <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>
{

    UIDocumentInteractionController *docController;

}
```

In your *.m file add this

```
/************************
 * Dropbox ACTION
 ************************/
-(IBAction) dropBoxAction2
{
    NSLog(@"dropBoxAction2 ...");

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask ,YES);
    NSString* documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSMutableString *fileNameStr3 = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"test_VCARD_Backup.vcf"];
    NSString* vcardDataFileStr = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameStr3];


    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:vcardDataFileStr];
    docController = [self setupControllerWithURL:fileURL
                                   usingDelegate:self];

    bool didShow = [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:self.view.bounds inView:self.view animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"didShow %d ...", didShow);

    if (!didShow)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR"
                                                        message:@"Sorry. The appropriate apps are not found on this device."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}


#pragma mark - UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate
- (UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL:(NSURL *)fileURL
                                               usingDelegate:(id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>)         interactionDelegate {

    UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController =
    [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
    interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;

    return interactionController;
}

- (UIViewController *)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    return self;
}

- (UIView *)documentInteractionControllerViewForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    return self.view;
}

- (CGRect)documentInteractionControllerRectForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    return self.view.frame;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`UIActivityViewController` only shows standard built-in activities plus any custom activities you pass as `applicationActivities`.

For what you are doing, you don't want `UIActivityViewController`. You want a `UIDocumentInteractionController`. If you just want to display existing apps that can open the file, use one of the `presentOpenInMenuFrom...` methods.

But note that is to be used for just a single file, not three.

Passing three files makes no sense in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I have used your code here to open with dropbox and only after I have used presentPreview method (bellow) It was worked for me.
The pdf was shown as preview and then on the preview share button click (top right) the dropbox option ("open in dropbox") did the job. As it works in the mail app in the attachment preview.

```
[interactionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
```

When i tried to open with presentOpenInMenuFromRect it was crashed on selecting "open in dropbox".